# Are there any words in English pronounced with /eː/ which aren't spelt with a following "r"?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling-pronunciations

In Australian English (non-rhotic) the word "air" is pronounced /eː/, in Canadian English (rhotic) it is pronounced /ɛɹ/ and most other dialects pronounce it as somewhere between those two. All the words I know of with that sound have an "r" as part of the spelling of the sound, e.g. h**ai*r***, c**a*r*e**, th**e*r*e**, b**ea*r***, **ae*r***oplane. Are there any words which have the same sound where the spelling does not include an "r"?

Comment: As far as I am aware, [e:] is not phonemic in any dialect of English: the only place where it occurs at all is as the phonetic realisation of /ɛə/, which is basically Antipodean and South African English. Some dialects of Scottish, however, do pronounce /e/ as [e̞], rather than [ɛ], in some contexts, and also lengthen stressed vowels in some contexts, so that _better_ is pronounced very close to [be̞:tər], which is almost the same sound.

Comment: And I believe some American dialects pronounce /eɪ/ as a monophthong before a voiceless consonant, so you get *wait* [wet] but *wade* [weɪd].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yeah**

This is the only word I could think of/find online with the same pronunciation that isn't spelt with an 'r'. There are a lot of different endings with this pronunciation, but this is the only one which ends with "-eah". (There are probably more words with the sound in the middle, but it was harder to search for them.)

Maybe it's not a coincidence that the only word which doesn't have this pronunciation because of a non-rhotic accent is an interjection!

Comment: Good example! In my accent "yeah" certainly does rhyme with "air". I may use this as a teaching example: "In Australian accents an 'r' is only sounded if it's followed by a vowel sound. Otherwise, it modifies the sound of the vowel just before it. So '**air**' is pronounced the same as the end of 'y **eah**'." Otherwise, it's tricky to explain non-rhotic accents using examples. I think that this is so uncommon that there are unlikely to be any more examples that most people would be familiar with.

Comment: I'd recommend checking that explanation of non-rhoticity on the Linguistics site... I would explain it more in terms of syllable boundaries than whether it's followed by a vowel or not.

Comment: Imagine teaching someone from India whose native language always sounds spelt "r"s. To them it would be confusing why Australians apparently randomly don't pronounce "r"s in words spelt with them. A 99% accurate explanation is better than "I don't know, you'll just have to learn them all as exceptions". Can you give me any examples where the rule as I've stated it doesn't work? car - [kaː], car alarm [kaː.ɹəlaːm] (the "r" from "car" is attached to the first "a" from "alarm" but the "r" in "alarm" is not voiced). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_English_phonology#Consonants

Comment: Fair enough, I guess it's a stronger rule than I would've expected.

Comment: FWIW, in standard American English, the vowel of "yeah" is /æ/, the same as in "cat".

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering under the assumption you're talking about /eə/ as shown [here.](http://teflpedia.com/IPA_phoneme_/e%C9%99/)

I haven't encountered any words without the *r* spelling pronounced this way *in general*, but I have in some American accents. I've heard words like *ma'am* and *damn* said this way in particular.

I hadn't heard the term before, but Google came up with ["æ tensing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_short_A#Phonemic_.C3.A6_tensing_in_the_Mid-Atlantic_region), and a good bit of information about it.

Answer (score -5):

No such thing as an "American accent" to the poster other than me who had written that.

The reason why is because the United States houses millions of people, most of which are from different backgrounds and cultures too.

Anyways, some words to answer O.P.'s question are "echo," "echolalia," "echondriac," and even "echelons".

Comment: This is a good answer for many American accents (not all), but the poster is asking about Australian.

Comment: Do not mistake /e/ for /ɛ/.

Comment: None of the words provided here contains /e:/ or even /e/.

Comment: @tchrist: the poster is asking for a word that contains the same vowel as *fared*. In many American accents, *fed* works (although they're both /ɛ/ and not /e/), which is why I said it was a good answer for many American accents.

Comment: @PeterShor Me, I say [fe˞d] not [fɛ˞d] for *fared*.  You can write those with [ɹ] if you want, and maybe /eɪ/, so perhaps [fe(ɪ)ɹd] but I have no [ɛ] in *fared* as I have in *fed*. I guess I have the ***fairy–ferry* merger.** :)

Comment: @tchrist: I have the *fairy-ferry* merger as well, but for me *fared* [fɛ˞d] has the same vowel as *fed* [fɛd]. I think [fe˞d] and [fɛ˞d] are allophones for accents with the *fairy-ferry* merger.

Comment: @Peter, it's not entirely clearly worded, but I _think_ what the OP is asking is for words that contain [e:], not words that contain the same vowel as _air_.

Comment: @tchrist I pronounce fairy as /feːɹi:/ and ferry as /feɹi:/.In Australian English /eː/ and /e/ _are_ phonemic.

Comment: Damn Stackexchange edit rules! @JanusBahsJacquet I pronounce fairy as /feːɹi:/ and ferry as /feɹi:/. In Australian English /eː/ and /e/ _are_ phonemic. Yes, I am looking for words that contain "long /e/" (as in "egg", not as in "see" which is actually a different vowel sound). but without the "r" sound that as far as I know always accompanies it. I understand this might sound different in other accents so if you have comparable examples I can say the word in my own accent to see if it fits. It doesn't have to be /eː/ in your accent, just the same sound as "air" but without the "r".

Comment: @CJ, what words do you pronounce with [ɛ(:)], then? Standard AuE doesn't have a phonemic distinction between an open and a closed /e/ (same as other dialects). So if I'm getting you right here, you're basically looking for a phonemic long /e/ in English, correct? To my knowledge, no such phoneme exists in any dialect of English; it is not part of any of the lexical sets commonly used, and it's definitely not a diaphoneme.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects which I agree with for AuE IPA symbols. AuE doesn't use [ɛ(ː)], it has [e(ː)] instead, which might sound like [ɛ(ː)(ɹ)] to someone whose accent includes that sound. Remember that AuE is non-rhotic. This is more a non-rhotic question as it is very unlikely in a rhotic accent that a word with "r" would be pronounced without /ɹ/ but in a non-rhotic accent maybe it's possible for a word _spelt_ without "r" to use the same sound as a word with a non-rhotic silent "r"? I'm guessing the answer is no, however.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What British English users have as an /eə/ phoneme is quite often much closer to [e:], for Australian English where it's alomost universal, /e:/ is a much better representation of the phoneme. The following might be helpful in deciphering Australian posters' posts: [Australian English phonemic representation](http://clas.mq.edu.au/speech/phonetics/transcription/phonemic_transcription/phonemic_transcription.html)